# Google Chrome - What are the "recommended policies" that can't be managed by policy?

Tags: google-chrome, gpo

In the below link at the beginning of the page they are referring to ("recommended policies").

---

*Not all user preferences are managed through policy, typically because they do not need to be managed centrally.
If you are looking to set policies that should be editable by the user ("recommended policies"), you may want to follow bug ...

---

Can someone please guide me to a list of these "recommended policies"?
I'm trying to find out if most of CONTENT-Settings under Privacy & Security are part of these "recommended policies" and can't be managed centrally by admins.

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences

Comment: Hi, TesterBoy. Welcome to stackoverflow, please read the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before make a question. Not all questions work well in stackoverflow format. Avoid unnecessaries comments like "thank you".

Comment: from my point of view comments like "thank you" are always necessarily among civilized people.